# Access Symfony2 service layer in Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, lifecycle

I'm sure the title is pretty descriptive, but for a more in depth question: **How does one access Symfony2's service layer for use in Doctrine's lifecycle callbacks?** I plan on utilizing these callbacks to register an entity in my search index (which is managed by another service) every time it is created/updated/deleted.

There are a couple of things that come to mind, though, so I might as well ask them as well...
Is this illegal, bad practice, or just plain terrible? **Is there another solution to hooking logic involving services into the entity's lifecycle** or should I decouple them altogether?

I dig any advice and am down to try new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) entry.